# How to use the subscribed cmd_vel?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i calculate the geometry_msgs::Twist cmd_vel and can subscribe to this topic /myrobot/cmd_vel successfully.
But i don't know how to use it, e.g. send it directly to my robot? I mean I can call back with velCallback, but how to use the velocity, in the main() function or in the velCallback() function if i want to send it to the robot? I hope i express my question clearly.
Below is the simple subscriber node.

---

#include "ros/ros.h"

#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

using namespace std;

void velCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist& vel)
{

```
cout<<"velocity\n"<<vel<<"\n";
```

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "myrobot_cmd_vel");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/myrobot/cmd_vel", 10, velCallback);

ros::spin();
return 0;
```

}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190359/how-to-use-the-subscribed-cmd_vel?/) by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2014-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you're writing a driver which receives Twist messages on the cmd_vel topic to control a custom mobile base.

In this case, you have to read the contents of the message and convert it into motor commands.

For a normal diff-drive robot, this means reading the `linear.x` (forward/backward) and `angular.z` (angular velocity) members of the Twist message and computing velocities for the left and right wheels.

For more complex robots, the other members of the Twist message represent sidways, up/down, and rotational motion around the other axes of the robot.

Note that, by convention, the units on the Twist message are in *meters per second* for linear velocities, and *radians per second* for angular velocities.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2014-08-15**:
Hi, thanks for your response. Actually I am writing a driver for a robot arm, the linear and angular velocities are for the arm's 6 degree of freedom. Can you explain how to read the Twist message to send it directly to the arm?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-15**:
Twist messages represent a free motion in space, and don't accurately capture the kinematics of an arm. You should probably look into the JointTrajectoryAction interface instead. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with arms, so I don't have any good references on the subject.